# Spring Webflux: Return statuscode and message based on exception thrown

Tags: error-handling, spring-webflux, mongorepository

How to determine which exception is thrown and get the status code out of it in Spring Webflux.
This is the structure of my controller code.

```
@GetMapping("/")
    fun getResults() : Mono<ResponseEntity<AccountDTO>>{
        return Service.getResult()
                .map {                     
                                       
                }.doOnError {
                    //how to get statuscode here
                    throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, it.message!!)
                }
```

Here I can get the custom message thrown, but how to get the status code? Instead of HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND. I want to capture the status code that is thrown by the service layer. Or is there a way to get the exception thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I found a solution that works. 
@GetMapping("/")
    fun getResults() : Mono<ResponseEntity<AccountDTO>>{
        return Service.getResult()
                .map {                     
                                       
                }.doOnError {
                   if(it is NotFoundException)
                    {
              
                        throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                 
                    }
                    else{
                        throw ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    }
                    
                }
```